# Exception Handling in C# Research Paper

Tags: c#, exception

Good day

I am a final year student at a IT Varsity, and for my final project i want to write a research paper on "Exception Handling in C#".

I need help on understanding Exception Handling better and need some good references.

Cant find a descent paper on my topic on the internet.

Please help me

Comment: Consider google as your best friend read the top 20 results and you good to go.

Comment: first hit on google. Seems pretty "descent":  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx

Comment: You're going to have a very hard time writing a research paper on exception handling in C# if you have to ask a question like this. Pick a topic that you already know something about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are some good resource to start with

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leino/papers/krml135.pdf

http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Exceptions.pdf

http://www.roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0107.html

google is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

These may help:

[Exceptions and Exceptions Handling (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Introduction to Exception Handling](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson15.aspx)

[C# Exception Handling and Debugging](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Exception_Handling_and_Debugging)

[Exception classes](http://en.csharp-online.net/Exception_classes)

Answer (score 0):

The [Common Language Infrastructure spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) would probably be a good place to start.